Getting Timeout Kafka exception org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=deleteRecords(api=METADATA)
I am facing kafka timeout exception. Error is:
partition: B3-0 error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=deleteRecords(api=METADATA), deadlineMs=1721138713548, tries=721498, nextAllowedTryMs=1721138714452) timed out at 1721138713557 after 721498 attempt(s)

We are using cp-kafka-connect from dockerhub confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.6.1
Using kafka connect maven version as below
<kafka.version>2.5.1</kafka.version>
<kafka-connect.version>2.5.1</kafka-connect.version>

We have not upgraded to most recent kafka recent version because of some issues but zookeeper maven is upgraded to recent 3.7.2
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Also kafka-log4j appender was upgraded
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

Below are all kafka related dependencies
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-avro-converter</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.eventstreams.connect</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-mq-sink</artifactId>
        <version>${connector.third.party.kafka-connect-mq.version-sink}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/${connector.third.party.jars}/kafka-connect-mq-sink-1.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.eventstreams.connect</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-mq-source</artifactId>
        <version>${connector.third.party.kafka-connect-mq.version-source}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${basedir}/${connector.third.party.jars}/kafka-connect-mq-source-1.3.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-connect.version}</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-connect.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>connect-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-connect.version}</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


It's not really clear how maven fits in here. Are you building a connector, or running one in that container? Also, that container is using Kafka version 3.6.x, not 2.5.1 or 3.7.0.

I am running one in that container. using old versions of kafka connect and old cp-kafka-connect docker works, but upgrading doesnt seem to work.  kafka connect 2.5.1 and cp-kakka connect docker 5.5.1 is compatible

If your brokers and Zookeeper nodes are running try and extend the timeout duration
request.timeout.ms=30000
But to me it seems like a version mismatch in your dependencies so you can use Maven Enforcer Plugin to detect conflicts or manually visualize dependency tree
